# Cómo usar fecha de typescript en input de tipo date?

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs-2.0

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano. 
Estoy empezando con Angular2. Quiero usar un input de tipo date, pero quiero poner como valor mínimo la fecha de hoy más un dia(o sea mañana). 
La fecha de hoy la puedo sacar con tipescript, pero no es del mismo formato que el que usa el input. La pregunta es, cómo puedo usar la fecha que saco de typescript en el input sin tener problemas de formato? 
Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Si no pones nada de código me es mas dificil serte mas concreto pero digamos que tu puedes componer el objeto que reciba el input.

1. Creas el objeto tipo date con TS
2. Creas el objeto que necesitas para el input
3. Mezclas las propiedasdes de estos objetos para componer uno válido.

Espero ser de ayuda y si no puedes poner una pregunta más completa?